# i cant figure out why my import/export is not working

Tags: javascript, function, import, export, alert

so i am trying to get practice using import and export with javascript. i keep getting errors, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'" and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" its just a simple alert function i am exporting from page1 and importing to main.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>module</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src= "JS/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src= "JS/main.js"></script>
    <script src= "JS/page1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS/page1:

```
export function myAlert() {
    alert("My Import/Export worked");
}
```

JS/main:

```
import {myAlert} from "./page1"

window.onload = myAlert;
```

Comment: you know it is available starting from ES6 right? You can use babel to avoid this error: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: i switched my code to what babel said and still same errors

Answer (score 0):

If you use babel standalone version this is the way: https://babeljs.io/setup#installation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>module</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script text="text/babel">

    // Your js code will be here

    </script>
    <script src= "JS/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src= "JS/main.js"></script>
    <script src= "JS/page1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will use your code with https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core#transform

`babel.transform(code: string, options?: Object, callback: Function)`

But this is a very inconvenient way of using babel, so I recommend you to use it with a bundler such as Webpack and install babel with npm install, so all these details will be handled by webpack: https://webpack.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Use `import {myAlert} from "./page1.js"` (include `.js` in path)
2. No need to include `<script src= "JS/page1.js"></script>` in your HTML
3. Use `type="module"` on module script tag (`<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>`)

#### Codes:

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>module</title>
<script src="JS/main.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

JS/page1.js:

```js
export function myAlert() {
    alert("My Import/Export worked");
}
```

JS/main.js:

```js
import {myAlert} from "./page1.js"

window.onload = myAlert;
```

Comment: "Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/jmish/OneDrive/Desktop/projects/Module%20Tetris%20Test/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

and

"GET file:///C:/Users/jmish/OneDrive/Desktop/projects/Module%20Tetris%20Test/main.js net::ERR_FAILED"

are the 2 errors i got after your changes

Comment: @JoeMisheski You should access the page from `http://` not `file://`. To start an HTTP server, try [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or [`python -m http.server 8000`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).